# Downloading old Document Object files on a public community

Tags: lightning-web-components, community

We've got some files stored as documents, which apparently predate notes and attachments, or were used in parallel to them. I'm trying to allow a download of this from a LWC. I've tried like every permutation of the servlet URL and I can't find one that results in a download. Just keep getting invalid page. I've given read access to the document object on the profile.

Here's what I've tried

```
/communityName/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=documentid
/communityName/s/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=documentid
/communityName/sfc/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=documentid
/communityName/sfsites/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=documentid
```

Anyone run into this kind of thing before? Do I need to upload these as contentDocuments? There's thousands and I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Is [lightning navigation open file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_open_files) helpful here? Otherwise you may need to use [URL class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_url.htm) to generate the base URL and prepend in your relative URL to make it absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raul's comment below was helpful, but I ended up going a different route. Not exactly a solution, but with the time it'll buy I can convert these to files and use the URL class Raul suggested.

I just linked directly to the existing visualforce community, since it was able to serve up documents. ie. visualforcecommunityurl/documentId.